# Error of "Invalid OAuth target" has occurred on some using Provisoning API Marketplace v1 applications

Tags: google-apps-marketplace, google-provisioning-api

I develop 3 unpublish Google Apps Marketplace(v1) applications that use Google Provisioning API with same scopes(prov_user, prov_group, prov_nickname and contact).
There was no problem where I run 3 applications three months ago, There are problem that 403 "Invalid OAuth Target" has occurred in the 2 applications.

I confirmed Marketplace v1 and Installed Google Apps settings but these has not changed from three months ago.

I think that the best solution is migration to Marketplace v2 and Directory API but I can not right now there for various reasons.
I want you to tell me the solution use Marketplace v1 and Provisioning API.

Comment: We had this error about a month and a half ago. So we decided to do the migration to the new marketplace earlier than we have planned. I suggest you migrate, and use the new APIs. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks your comment.
The support center of Google answered that Since OAuth v1 was deprecated, If OAuth v1 application has not been used for several months, Google will set that its authorization request is not accepted.
So, the solution without Marketplace v2 migration, there is only to ask Google to get to accept the authorization request, but that is Time-consuming and not general.
Therefore, We have modified plan to migrate to Marketplace v2 as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be a poor idea to use the provisioning api at this point, since the provisioning api has been marked as deprecated, https://developers.google.com/google-apps/provisioning/.

Apps that are currently published and installed will into a domain will work for a while, but new customers/domains will not. You're best bet is to switch to the Directory api as soon as you can.